# Как обновить конкретную область на QGraphicsScene?

Tags: c++, qt, gui

Собственно, вопрос следующий:
Есть у меня QGraphicsView у которого есть QGraphicsScene.
Для QGraphicsScene установлен следующий режим:

```
QGraphicsView::setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::NoViewportUpdate)
```

Т.е. картинка не будет обновляться, пока я явно не вызову метод update().
Далее, к примеру, раз в 20 мс я вызываю QGraphicsScene::update() (именно без аргументов). В таком случае все работает так, как надо. Однако, насколько я понимаю, если у update() нет аргументов, то обновляется весь QGraphicsScene::sceneRect(), что в моем случае является существенно неоптимальным. Когда я пытаюсь явно задать область, которая должна быть обновлена, ничего не обновляется. Т.е. даже, если я пишу так:

```
QGraphicsScene::update(QGraphicsScene::sceneRect());
```

То ничего не обновляется. Помогите разобраться, как это работает.

Comment: Что возвращает QGraphicsScene::sceneRect() ?

Comment: @awesome Собственно то, что и должен возвращать этот метод - прямоугольник вида {0, 0, width, heigth}.